# Detection limit in function of measured false negative rate

Tags: distributions, classification, statistical-significance, confidence-interval

Suppose that a given device returns a type II error rate of 5% when trying to detect the presence of a physical effect (in my specific case, the presence of a radioactive source, from which said device can observe 50 gamma emissions). How may I calculate the necessary amount of observable emissions if I want to bring this false negative rate to 1%?

The idea comes from a book written by Eric W. Abelquist, "Decommissioning Health Physics: A Handbook for MARSSIM users", which has the following excerpt:

"(...) lowering the type II error rate increases the detection limit -- eg. suppose that 50 net counts are dectable 95% of the time, then it might take 66 net counts to be detected 99% of the time -- while increasing the type II error rate decreases the detection limit".

How did the author come to this conclusion?